# EPPlus Not Editing Excel File from SharePoint: Worksheets[0] Is Empty

Tags: c#, excel, file, sharepoint, epplus

I'm working with SharePoint Client Object Model and EPPlus in C# to edit an Excel file retrieved from SharePoint. While fetching the file and saving it back work fine using OpenBinaryDirect and SaveBinaryDirect, I encounter an issue where Worksheets[0] is empty, preventing any edits.

Here's the simplified code:

```
// Fetch the file
var filePathSource = "/sites/.../file.xlsx";
FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, filePathSource);

// Attempt to edit with EPPlus
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInformation.Stream))
{
    if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count > 0) {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "New Value"; // Edit attempt
    } else {
        // The issue: Worksheet[0] is empty or not accessible
        Console.WriteLine("Worksheet is empty.");
    }

    using (var editedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        package.SaveAs(editedStream);
        editedStream.Position = 0; // Prepare for upload

        // Save back to SharePoint
        var filePathDest = "/sites/.../editedFile.xlsx";
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, filePathDest, editedStream, true);
    }
}
```

Despite the file being successfully fetched and saved, Worksheets[0] appears empty, and I'm unable to make any edits.

Question: How can I access and edit the Excel file's content when Worksheets[0] comes up empty? Is there a step I'm missing or a common pitfall with EPPlus and SharePoint integration?

Looking for guidance on this issue. Thanks!

Edit: When I save it locally it works fine. But in my case I can't do it. It all should be stored in the memory.

Comment: Did you try to save those files locally and open them? Do they contain anything?

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that SharePoint isn't a local disk. It's a remote web app so when you try to read from the (deprecated) `FileInformation.Stream` you're actually reading from the HTTP stream. It's safer (and faster, using less RAM) to save the file locally first, open that local file, modify it and finally upload that back to the server. Right now you're keeping 2 copies of the contents in memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When I save it locally it works fine. But in my case, I can't do it. I need to do everything with the memory.

Comment: Why can't you do it? Even in a web app, even in a container, you can write to a temporary folder and delete the file afterwards. If you use the `DeleteOnClose` flag when you create the file, it will be deleted automatically

Comment: The other option is to copy the data into a MemoryStream and use that with `ExcelPackage`. That adds one more copy of the data though. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML files. An HTTP stream can only move forward and the stream itself is closed when the *server* closes it or times out. Perhaps a slow connection causes the SharePoint client to close the stream prematurely, or EPPlus has problems with a slow forward-only stream?

Comment: Another problem may be that you're using an obsolete SharePoint client library. CSOM was introduced at a time when SharePoint was almost exclusive an on-premise offering. There was little reason to include resilience, retries etc in the first client libraries. Now that SharePoint is almost exclusively cloud based, network issues are guaranteed

Comment: How would the OpenBinary and SaveBinary look with Graph? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?